# Java 8 Stream + Map + ForEach + Collect

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am reading values from a File and get List.
like below -

```
List<String> fields = Utils.readFile("myText.txt", true);
```

Once I get this `List<String>` I want to iterate through this list and pass each value to a function which uses this value, queries into DB and prepares a `List<MyCustomObject>` and returns the same.

Implementing in Java 7 is quite easy but I'm unable to get it in Java 8 using Stream + Map/forEach + Collect operations.

I have tried the below -

```
Utils.readFile("myText-"+".txt", true)
        .stream()
        .map(str -> getListOfCustomObjForEachStr(str, pstmt))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it returns a `List<List<MyCustomObject>>` instead of merged `List<MyCustomObject>`

getListOfCustomObjForEachStr() method returns a List for each input str passed in the above code. And I need a merged List

Can someone please guide me what can be done here to get a merged list? (I'm new to Java 8 so it might seem a silly question but any help is appreciated)

**Edit 1**
Got this implemented like below using FlatMap -
Kindly suggest if any other better way to do it. Hope it helps someone somewhere someday :) Keep sharing.

```
List<MyCustomObjects> = Utils.readFile("myText-"+".txt", true)
    .stream()
    .map(str -> getListOfCustomObjForEachStr(str, pstmt))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am guessing that 'getListOfCustomObjForEachStr(str, pstmt)' returns a List<MyCustomObject>, which is why you get a list of lists.  If your map function can return just one object then you would be fine.

Comment: @JamesBlack : But in DB I have a list of values against each input string. Hence I have to collaborate/merge the individual lists and prepare a final list. This is the reason getListOfCustomObjForEachStr returns List<MyCustomObject> instead of MyCustomObject. I hope you are understanding my concern. Let me know otherwise will try to reframe it.

Comment: @SwapnilJaju `flatMap()`, as you added to your edit in the question, is the way to go if you want to _flatten_ the lists into one.

Comment: `flatMap` if you don't require intermediate results (like `List<List<String>>`). Otherwise if you need them you could still call `reduce` afterwards. By the way: do you know `Files.lines` already? It returns a `Stream<String>` of lines.

Comment: @Magnilex : thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Roland : For my current task I do not require intermediate results. As spotted by Holger in the below comment, I am able to use flatmap directly instead of map+flatmap. Regarding Files.lines I understand it returns a stream<String> of lines which is exactly what I want for my use. Do you see any concerns/issues with that? Kindly point out, if yes. I'll take that into consideration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `flatMap` is the canonical way to get a flat list. You may use a single step instead of `map`+`flatMap`:

```
List<MyCustomObjects> list = Utils.readFile("myText-"+".txt", true)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(str -> getListOfCustomObjForEachStr(str, pstmt).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may think about an alternative to `getListOfCustomObjForEachStr` returning a `Stream` in the first place. Further, not the existence of `Files.lines`, which returns a stream of line strings without filling a temporary `List` first.

In this specific case, there is an alternative. Considering that `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is equivalent to `.collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll)`¹, you also use

```
List<MyCustomObjects> list = Utils.readFile("myText-"+".txt", true)
    .stream()
    .map(str -> getListOfCustomObjForEachStr(str, pstmt))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

replacing `add` with `addAll`, which is already sufficient to add all sub-`List<MyCustomObjects>`s to the result `List<MyCustomObjects>`.

---

¹ That’s how `toList()` works now, but since it not specified to do this, it might be different in other versions

Comment: Holger : Thanks for the suggesstion. Can you please point out which is the better approach to follow?
Using flatMap+Collect(Collectors.toList()) or map+Collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll)

Comment: For this specific case and the current Java version, the second variant might have a slightly better performance, but the first variant is the general pattern, that you would also apply when solving similar tasks which the second variant can’t solve.